# filename and contenttype of upload image

Tags: image, upload

how to get the name of the file and the content type of the image which we uploaded in mvc application please tell me its urgent

thanks
ritz

Comment: What web server, operating system, language?

Answer (score 0):

```
May be below code will be helpful..

//index..
<?php 
require_once("include/DBConnect.php");
include_once('header.php');
?>
<div align="center">
<h1 style="color:red">Welcome </h1>
<br/>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
<input name="ImageFile" type="file" />
<input type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Upload" />
</form>
</div>
<?php include_once('footer.php');?>

//upload

<?php
require_once("include/DBConnect.php");
require_once("include/FunctionGeneral.php");
include_once('header.php');
if(isset($_POST))
{
    $ThumbSquareSize        = 200; //Thumbnail will be 200x200
    $BigImageMaxSize        = 500; //Image Maximum height or width
    $ThumbPrefix            = "thumb_"; //Normal thumb Prefix
    $DestinationDirectory   = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory ends with / (slash)
    $Quality                = 90;

    // check $_FILES['ImageFile'] array is not empty
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']))
    {
            die('Something went wrong with Upload!'); // output error .
    }

    // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 

    // Elements (values) of $_FILES['ImageFile'] array
    //let's access these values by using their index position
    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['ImageFile']['name'])); 
    $ImageSize      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['size']; // Obtain original image size
    $TempSrc        = $_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
    $ImageType      = $_FILES['ImageFile']['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

    switch(strtolower($ImageType))
    {
        case 'image/png':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $CreatedImage =  imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/pjpeg':
            $CreatedImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name']);
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error and exit
    }

    //PHP getimagesize() function returns height-width from image file stored in PHP tmp folder.
    list($CurWidth,$CurHeight)=getimagesize($TempSrc);
    //Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);

    //remove extension from filename
    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName); 

    //Construct a new image name (with random number added) for our new image.
    $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNumber.'.'.$ImageExt;

    //set the Destination Image
    $thumb_DestRandImageName    = $DestinationDirectory.'thumbnail/'.$ThumbPrefix.$NewImageName; //Thumb name
    $DestRandImageName          = $DestinationDirectory.$NewImageName; //Name for Big Image

    //Resize image to our Specified Size by calling resizeImage function.
    if(resizeImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$BigImageMaxSize,$DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
    {
        //Create a square Thumbnail right after, this time we are using cropImage() function
        if(!cropImage($CurWidth,$CurHeight,$ThumbSquareSize,$thumb_DestRandImageName,$CreatedImage,$Quality,$ImageType))
            {
                echo 'Error Creating thumbnail';
            }
        /*
        At this point we have succesfully resized and created thumbnail image
        We can render image to user's browser or store information in the database
        For demo, we are going to output results on browser.
        */

        echo '<div id="output">';
        echo '<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="'.$thumb_DestRandImageName.'" alt="Thumbnail"></td>';
        echo '</tr><tr>';
        echo '<td align="center"><img src="'.$DestRandImageName.'" alt="Resized Image"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
        /*
        // Insert info into database table!
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO myImageTable (ImageName, ThumbName, ImgPath)
        VALUES ($DestRandImageName, $thumb_DestRandImageName, 'uploads/')");
        */
        $added = getCurDate();
        $title = "test";//$dbObj->escape_special_char($_POST['title']);
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = "rakhi";
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $fields = "`photo_title` ,`createuser` ,`image_name` ,`added`";
        $values = "'$title','$user_id','$NewImageName','$added'";
    }else{
        die('Resize Error'); //output error
    }
}
include_once('footer.php');
?>
```